# How to populate Syncfusion sfDataGrid with nested view?

Tags: vb.net, syncfusion, sfdatagrid

I have been trying for hours to manually populate the grid with a nested view, I have read the documentation but for some reason I can't get it to work. I can do it by setting the AutoGenerateRelations and AutoGenerateColumns to true. But I need to define the column header text manually since the names coming form the query are not user readable friendly.

[image: Nested Grid]

```
Private Sub populateGrid(byval ds as DataSet)

             Dim ds As New DataSet()
             ds.Tables.Add(JORs)
             ds.Tables.Add(JORItems)

             ds.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("InventoryItems", ds.Tables(0).Columns("JORNo"), ds.Tables(1).Columns("JORNo")))
             SfDataGrid1.AutoGenerateRelations = True
             SfDataGrid1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
             SfDataGrid1.DataSource = ds

             'gridviewdefinition for datagrid
             Dim gridviewdefinition = New GridViewDefinition()
             gridviewdefinition.RelationalColumn = "InventoryItems"
             grididviewdefinition.DataGrid = New SfDataGrid() With {.Name = "firstlevelnestedgrid", .AutoGenerateColumns = False}
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "Doc ID", .HeaderText = "Doc ID"})
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "Doctype", .HeaderText = "Document Type"})
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "Crew", .HeaderText = "Crew"})
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "JORNo", .HeaderText = "JOR No"})
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "Salesman", .HeaderText = "Salesman"})
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "Company", .HeaderText = "Company"})
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "Well Name", .HeaderText = "Well Name"})
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "Description", .HeaderText = "Description"})
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "ScheduledDate", .HeaderText = "Shed Date"})
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "Status", .HeaderText = "Status"})
             
             Dim gridviewdefinition2 = New GridViewDefinition()
             gridviewdefinition2.RelationalColumn = "JORNo"
             gridviewdefinition2.DataGrid = New SfDataGrid() With {.Name = "secodlevelnestedgrid", .AutoGenerateColumns = False}
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "JORNo", .HeaderText = "JOR No"})
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "product", .HeaderText = "Product ID"})
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "description", .HeaderText = "Product Name"})
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "QTYHours", .HeaderText = "QTY Hours"})
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "rate", .HeaderText = "Rate"})
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "cost", .HeaderText = "Cost"})
             SfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "partNo", .HeaderText = "Part Number"})
                                     
             SfDataGrid1.DetailsViewDefinitions.Add(gridviewdefinition)
             SfDataGrid1.DetailsViewDefinitions.Add(gridviewdefinition2)
            
      End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

You can modify the column header text for both the parent DataGrid and the DetailsView DataGrid when `AutoGenerateColumns and AutoGenerateRelations are set to true` by handling the AutoGeneratingColumn event. Here is an example code snippet:

```
Dim DataSource As DataTable = GetDataTable()
sfDataGrid1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
sfDataGrid1.AutoGenerateRelations = True
sfDataGrid1.AutoGeneratingColumn += SfDataGrid1_AutoGeneratingColumn
sfDataGrid1.AutoGeneratingRelations += SfDataGrid1_AutoGeneratingRelations
sfDataGrid1.DataSource = DataSource

Private Sub SfDataGrid1_AutoGeneratingColumn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal 
e As Syncfusion.WinForms.DataGrid.Events.AutoGeneratingColumnArgs)
    'Here you can set your own column name based on its mapping name for 
    'Parent DataGrid
   If e.Column.MappingName = "JORNo" Then 
     e.Column.HeaderText = "Changed Name"
End Sub

Private Sub SfDataGrid1_AutoGeneratingRelations(ByVal sender As Object, 
ByVal e As 
Syncfusion.WinForms.DataGrid.Events.AutoGeneratingRelationsEventArgs)
       'In the DetailsViewDataGrid we should wire the AutoGeneratingColumn 
       'event for details grid.
   e.GridViewDefinition.DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += 
   DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn
 End Sub

Private Sub DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e 
As Syncfusion.WinForms.DataGrid.Events.AutoGeneratingColumnArgs)
    'Here you can set your own column name based on its mapping name for                
    'Details View DataGrid
    If e.Column.MappingName = "JORNo" Then 
       e.Column.HeaderText = "Changed Name"
 End Sub
```

**Approach 2:**

You can change the HeaderText of the columns by manually adding the columns to the DataGrid when the `AutoGenerateColumns and AutoGenerateRelations properties are set to false`.

```
this.sfDataGrid1.AutoGenerateRelations = false;
this.sfDataGrid1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

'columns for Parent Grid 

sfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "Doc ID", 
.HeaderText = "Doc ID"})
sfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = 
"Doctype", .HeaderText = "Document Type"})
sfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "Crew", 
.HeaderText = "Crew"})
sfDataGrid1.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "JORNo", 
.HeaderText = "JOR No"})

Dim jORgridviewdefinition = New GridViewDefinition()
'Set the Relation here
jORgridviewdefinition.RelationalColumn = "JORNo"
Dim childGrid As SfDataGrid = New SfDataGrid()
childGrid.AllowResizingColumns = True
childGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = False

childGrid.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "JORNo", 
.HeaderText = "JOR No"})
childGrid.Columns.Add(New GridTextColumn() With {.MappingName = "QTYHours", 
.HeaderText = "QTY Hours"})

jORgridviewdefinition.DataGrid = childGrid
'Add your relational definition to the datagrid ie. ParentGrid.
Me.sfDataGrid1.DetailsViewDefinitions.Add(jORgridviewdefinition)
```

Comment: on the second solution the relation needs to be jORgridviewdefinition.RelationalColumn = "InventoryItems". Thanks.